# Mathematical software for calculating Christoffel symbols, curvature, etc

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, tensor-calculus, software

I'm looking for a Mathematical software that can do the following:

I put in a metric (some kind of a two-dimensional matrix), and the software calculates Christoffel symbols, Ricci curvatures, Paneitz operators, etc.

What software should I use? Can I do this somewhere online?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for software and not physics concepts.

Comment: For quick calculations on a package that doesn't take much time to learn, I recommend GRQuick - http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8329/. I had never heard of Paneitz operator before I read your question. For a much more powerful package, but one that takes some time to learn, is xAct - http://www.xact.es/